# Torch - How to enable fp16?

Tags: torch

On [Soumith's benchmark](https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks/) there are both CUDNN[R4]-fp16 and CUDNN[R4]-fp32 benchmarks for Torch.

How can I enable floating point 16 on Torch ?

I found discussions such as [this one](https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch/pull/170) but it's not clear to me what to do with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to enable half precision. If cutorch.hasHalf is true, this should work;

```
require('cutorch')
a = torch.CudaHalfTensor(3)
b = torch.CudaHalfTensor(3)
print(torch.cmul(a,b))
```

If it doesn't, try updating cutorch to latest version;

```
luarocks install cutorch
```